# Convert from U1.8 to decimal

Tags: binary, hex

How do i convert a U1.8 number from hex to decimal? I saw many different ways each one results in a different answer - which is the correct one?
Even when trying to ask chatGPT each iteration results in a different answer (for the same input number).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.